# Can UI elements in a complicated storyboard effectively be mapped back to code?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, scene

I have a fairly complex storyboard that has lots of deprecated UI elements and scenes sprinkled throughout. I just want to delete some of this dead code, however, I can't get a good grasp on whether or not each UI element is actually attached to some code or not.

When I click a UI element, it shows some Send Events or a Referencing Outlet, but doesn't seem to map back to anything useful. Even if the code behind it has been long gone, it still shows a connection in the storyboard with no extra information.

What's the best way to go about auditing this storyboard?